# Displaying 180 degree stereoscopic video instead of 360?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, oculus, gopro

My VR-researcher friend asked me to develop a simple android (and eventually iOS) app for google cardboard that displays her 180 degree video. [She stitched it together from her gopro 3 hero rig, and it's in a quite unusual projection I believe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ORgd.png) I've been researching this a lot but I haven't seen anything like it, although I must admit I'm new to VR video.

Google's documentation for the cardboard specifies the equirectangular-panoramic projection as the only thing supported at the time and it doesn't seem like anyone uses this bizarre projection besides her. She normally loads it into koloreyes - where it looks perfectly fine - on her macbook and displays it on an Oculus and claims this projection based on the eyes curvature improves immersion, and I must agree it was deeply immersive when I tried it myself for her research project. ([Full length video available here, but youtube compresses it to a degree that ruins immersion completely which is why the app is even justified to begin with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLzPee7kwtQ)).

She would like a more portable version for demonstration with a modified cardboard with straps or something added, but when I load it into the simplevideowidget in the google VR SDK it looks terrible, presumably because of the unexpected projection.

Unity appears to be a no-go as it does not support high resolution videos without using expensive plugins like Easy Movie Texture. It also seems quite overkill to use unity just to display a video.

TL;DR: How do I display this oddly projected 180 degree stereoscopic video in an android app with the google VR SDK (or something entirely different?) Why does the video file work fine in the Oculus but not at all with the cardboard? I'm thinking it must have to do with the field of view, somehow.

Comment: This seems relevant, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. https://github.com/google/spatial-media/blob/master/docs/spherical-video-rfc.md#StereoMode

Comment: You might want to link to the reference for the 180 degree stereo video. You also might want to try Samsung VR to see if it can play the video since Samsung VR uses Oculus libraries.

Comment: The reference for the video? As in some sort of specification of what projection it is? I wish I knew, but I'm inquiring into it. I might know in the next few days. What is the purpose of trying the Samsung VR? I don't have access to one (but I guess I could try at a shop), but shouldn't it be exactly the same as the Oculus if it uses the same libraries?

Comment: Sorry, correct a video specification. With respect to Samsung, just providing options, if a general Android player isn't available, perhaps it would work on Samsung.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my question was too wordy - I replaced first link with a screenshot that illustrates my problem equally well. It's not that it won't play (it's a regular h264 encoded mp4) it's just that it must be some sort of 180° video projection that works great on the Oculus but not on the cardboard. Maybe my problem just is that the distance to screen on the cardboard is longer than the Oculus, as the video seems "zoomed out" when using the cardboard. That doesn't really make sense to me though. Is there any way to magnify the video in the cardboard SDK? Maybe that would help somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use from this example.May be this one will help you. In this change sphere to 180, 230 whatever you want. May be it helps you.

https://github.com/ashqal/MD360Player4Android